# Absorbing Markov chain when less transient states than absorbing states

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I  have a probability matrix:

```
   1    2    3
1  0.5  0.3  0.2
2    0    1    0
3    0    0    1
```

I understand that:

$$
Q = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0.5 \end{array} \right) \\
R = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0.3 & 0.2 \end{array} \right) \\
I = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array} \right)
$$

I calculated the fundamental matrix $ N $ to be:

$$
N = (I - Q)^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)
$$

But when I try to calculate the probability matrix, I can't do the multiplication because it's a $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix against a $ 1 \times 2 $ matrix. =S

$$
B = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} 0.3 & 0.2\end{array} \right)
$$

Comment: If $Q$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, then $(I-Q)$ must be $1\times 1$ as well, so $(I-Q)^{-1}$ would also be $1\times 1$, so it is unclear how you obtained a $2\times 2$ result for this.

Comment: Ah, my bad, then. I tried using a $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix for $ I $. I guess I had to use a matrix the size of $ Q $.

Comment: @Arkamis shouldn't you submit that as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: @JohnnyLee Once you solve the problem, feel free to add it as an answer to your own question, and after a few days, accept your own answer. Solving problems and submitting your work to review is an important process!

Answer (score 0):

So, as @Arkamis pointed out, what I had wrong is that $ (I-Q)^{-1} $ shouldn't be a $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix.

I started with a mistake in $ I - Q $ like this, which is **wrong**:

$$
I - Q= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) - \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$

One isn't to "expand" $ Q $ to fit $ I $. **Instead**, it should make $ I $ whatever the size of $ Q $:

$$
I - Q = (1) - (0.5)
$$